# List of NAN values while calculating p value and Z score in Scipy

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, statsmodels

I am calculating Z score and P value for different sub segments within a data frame.

The data frame has two columns, here are the top 5 values in my data frame:

```
df[["Engagement_score", "Performance"]].head()
   Engagement_score  Performance
0    6                 0.0
1    5                 0.0
2    7                 66.3
3    3                 0.0
4    11                0.0
```

Here's the distribution of engagement score: 
[image]

Here's the distribution of performance:
[image]

I am grouping my dataframe by engagement score and then I calculate these three statistics for those groups:

1) Average performance score(sub_average) and number of values within that group(sub_bookings)

2) Average performance score for rest of the groups(rest_average) and number of values in rest of the groups(rest_bookings)

Overall performance score and overall bookings are calculated for the overall data frame.

Here's my code to do that.

```
def stats_comparison(i):
    df.groupby(i)['Performance'].agg({
    'average': 'mean',
    'bookings': 'count'
    }).reset_index()
    cat = df.groupby(i)['Performance']\
        .agg({
            'sub_average': 'mean',
            'sub_bookings': 'count'
       }).reset_index()
    cat['overall_average'] = df['Performance'].mean()
    cat['overall_bookings'] = df['Performance'].count()
    cat['rest_bookings'] = cat['overall_bookings'] - cat['sub_bookings']
    cat['rest_average'] = (cat['overall_bookings']*cat['overall_average'] \
                     - cat['sub_bookings']*cat['sub_average'])/cat['rest_bookings']
    cat['z_score'] = (cat['sub_average']-cat['rest_average'])/\
        np.sqrt(cat['overall_average']*(1-cat['overall_average'])
            *(1/cat['sub_bookings']+1/cat['rest_bookings'])) 
    cat['prob'] = np.around(stats.norm.cdf(cat.z_score), decimals = 10) # this is the p value
    cat['significant'] = [(lambda x: 1 if x > 0.9 else -1 if x < 0.1 else 0)(i) for i in cat['prob']] 
    # if the p value is less than 0.1 then I can confidently say that the 2 samples are different. 
    print(cat)

stats_comparison('Engagement_score')
```

I get the following output when I execute my code:

```
     Engagement_score  sub_average  sub_bookings  overall_average  \
0                3       57.281118          1234        34.405373   
1                 4    56.165374           722        34.405373   
2                 5    52.896404           890        34.405373   
3                 6    50.275880           966        34.405373   
4                 7    43.475344          1018        34.405373   
5                 8    37.693290          1222        34.405373   
6                 9    30.418053          1695        34.405373   
7                10    16.458142          2874        34.405373   
8                11    25.604145          1375        34.405373   
9                12    10.910013           789        34.405373   

   overall_bookings  rest_bookings  rest_average  z_score  prob  significant  
0             12785          11551     31.961544      NaN   NaN            0  
1             12785          12063     33.102984      NaN   NaN            0  
2             12785          11895     33.021850      NaN   NaN            0  
3             12785          11819     33.108233      NaN   NaN            0  
4             12785          11767     33.620702      NaN   NaN            0  
5             12785          11563     34.057900      NaN   NaN            0  
6             12785          11090     35.014797      NaN   NaN            0  
7             12785           9911     39.609727      NaN   NaN            0  
8             12785          11410     35.465995      NaN   NaN            0  
9             12785          11996     35.950709      NaN   NaN            0
```

I don't know why I am getting a list of NAN values in ZScore and P value columns. There are no negative values in my data set.

I also get the following warning when I run the code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version


    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:15: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
      from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
      return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
      return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1738: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
      cond2 = (x >= self.b) & cond0
```

Comment: `np.sqrt(cat['overall_average']*(1-cat['overall_average'])...`: You'll always have a negative number under your square root given that overall average is around 34

Comment: @ALollz So, how do I modify my code?

Comment: @ALollz I have included an image that shows the distribution of both the variables.

Comment: You cannot use a `Z-test` here. The issue is that your subsample is correlated with the overall sample, so you violate the independence assumption of the `Z-test`. You should instead use a two-sample [`t-test`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) which tests the difference between the subsample and everything not in the subsample. That scipy function should do the entire calculation, just split the `DataFrame` into two groups.

Comment: @ALollz When I ran the t-test, I am getting the same t-value and probability value for all the groups.     Here's how I calculated the t-value: cat['t_value'] = stats.ttest_ind(cat['sub_average'], cat['rest_average'])[0]